# mysql if string is empty use default value

Tags: mysql

I have the following query, all the `''` come up as empty strings

```
INSERT INTO `locations` ( `house`,`house_number`,`road`,`city`,`state`,`country`,`country_code`,`supermarket`,`county`,`place_of_worship`,`city_district`,`suburb`,`neighbourhood`,`pedestrian`,`postcode`) 
VALUES ('','','','Gemeinde Wien','Vienna','Austria','at','','W','Saint Stephen\'s cathedral','Innere Stadt','Innere Stadt','Textilviertel','Stephansplatz','1010');
```

**table structure**

All fields have a default value of `null`.

**problem**

So the question is, how can I get it so that empty strings keep their default value?

Comment: You will need to either insert a value of NULL or modify your query to not insert anything for those columns if there is no value

Comment: Bummer, I had hoped mysql could take care of it :) Lazy php right here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of inserting `''`  you can just use null

```
INSERT INTO`locations`(`house`,`house_number`,`road`,`city`,`state`,`country`,`country_code`,`supermarket`,`county`,`place_of_worship`,`city_district`,`suburb`,`neighbourhood`,`pedestrian`,`postcode`) 
VALUES (null,null,null,'Gemeinde Wien','Vienna','Austria','at','','W','Saint Stephen\'s cathedral','Innere Stadt','Innere Stadt','Textilviertel','Stephansplatz','1010');
```

or do not insert anything like this

```
INSERT INTO `locations` (`city`,`state`,`country`,`country_code`,`supermarket`,`county`,`place_of_worship`,`city_district`,`suburb`,`neighbourhood`,`pedestrian`,`postcode`) 
VALUES ('Gemeinde Wien','Vienna','Austria','at','','W','Saint Stephen\'s cathedral','Innere Stadt','Innere Stadt','Textilviertel','Stephansplatz','1010');
```